# TensorFlow: reroute one input of an operator through a custom block

Tags: tensorflow

I've captured some interesting operations, say "Conv2D"s, in a TF network. The goal is to experiment some data manipulation on the weight input "weights". Let's call the data manipulation function "white_box_func".

I've done some reading of the [graph editor module](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.2/api_guides/python/contrib.graph_editor). It seems that I can wrap my "white_box_func" in a "tf.py_func". But then, the original "weights" tensor needs to be routed through the "py_func(white_box_func, ...)", whose output needs to be properly connected to the "Conv2D".

```
<weights> --
             \
              ===> Conv2D
             /
<features> --
```

becomes

```
<weights> --> <py_func(white_box_func,...)--
                                            \
                                             ===> Conv2D
                                            /
<features> --------------------------------
```

Having a hard time figuring out a clean way of doing that. Any suggestion is appreciated!

Comment: How are you constructing the graph in the first place? The cleanest way to do what you're doing is to add the `tf.py_func()` operations as the graph (and the `weights` node) is constructed.

Comment: @mrry, thank you for your reply. I've figured this one out. I'll clean it up a bit and share the solution with the SO community later today. Meanwhile, I have to log my complaints about how overly generic the low-level TF error messages are.

Comment: @mrry, my solution has been posted. Please let me know if it makes sense to you. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I've figured this one out. The code below shows how to edit a quantized node:

```
#Assuming <p> is the node we want to edit
for i in list(p.inputs):
    if tf.quint8 == i.dtype and 'weights' in i.name:
        orig_rtype = i.op.outputs[0].dtype
        new_rtype = tf.uint8 if tf.quint8 == orig_rtype else orig_rtype

        with p.graph.as_default():
            my_i = tf.py_func(my_shiny_func, i.op.outputs,
                              [new_rtype, tf.float32, tf.float32],
                              stateful=False, name=p.name + 'shiny')

            my_i_cast = tf.bitcast(my_i[0], orig_rtype)

            ge.connect(ge.sgv(my_i_cast.op, my_i[0].op),
                       ge.sgv(p).remap_inputs([1, 4, 5]))
```

Comment: FYI, <ge> refers to the tensorflow.contrib.graph_editor module here.